# "Unable to connect" using Mamp and MySQL (PHP)

Tags: php, database, sqlite, mamp

I am trying to access my MySQL database with PHP, but my page keeps returning the error "unable to connect". Here is my code:

```
echo '<ul>';

$db_host = "localhost";
$db_user = "user";

$db_link = mysqli_connect($db_host, $db_user, $db_password, $db_name)
or die ("Unable to connect");

$sqlQuery = "SELECT u.user_name, m.message_text, m.time_stamp FROM users AS u INNER JOIN messages m ON u.user_id = m.user_id";

$result = mysqli_query($db_link, $sqlQuery);


if($result)
{
 while ($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) 
  {
    echo "<li>" . $row['message_text'] . "<br>" . $row['user_name'] . "<br>" . $row['time_stamp'] . "</li>\n\t\t<hr>";
}
}
else
{
echo '<p>error displaying resultset</p>';
}

mysqli_close($db_link);
echo '</ul>';
```

Comment: You cannot connect to a sqlite database using `mysqli_*` functions. You should switch to PDO or the `sqlite_*` functions.

Comment: See the result of `mysqli_connect_error()` to see what's going wrong.

Comment: Thank you George Marques I did as you advised and this is the error I got "error displaying resultset"

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
$link = mysql_connect("localhost","root","") or die("Cannot connect to server");

$dbname="test";

mysql_select_db($dbname,$link) or die("Cannot connect to the database");

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you haven't set `$db_password` or `$db_name`, with the latter definitely necessary to connect to the database. The former should also be set assuming you have a password set for the database (you do have a password set, right?) Verify that you have properly set those variables, and then do a var_dump() on the $db_link like this:

```
echo "<pre>";     //For formatting. 
var_dump($db_link);
echo "</pre>"
```

This will give you an idea of whether or not you have properly setup the connection object for the database.

**UPDATE**

```
SELECT
    u.user_name,
    m.message_text,
    m.time_stamp
FROM
    users AS u
INNER JOIN messages m ON u.user_id = m.user_id
```

Here's your query, but with the proper formatting. Notice the last line, you have:

```
INNER JOIN messages m
```

That stray 'm' isn't necessary, and for the sake of debugging I'd recommend formatting the query like this:

```
$sqlQuery = "SELECT `user`.user_name, `message`.`message_text`, `message`.time_stamp FROM users INNER JOIN messages ON `users`.user_id = `message`.user_id";
```

*Edit:* As an aside, you mentioned that the query gave you a bool(false) when you used var_dump. This tells you that the query is failing and lets you know to start debugging it. [(PHP.net)](https://www.php.net/mysqli_query)

Comment: This is what it returns:object(mysqli)#1 (19) {
  ["affected_rows"]=>
  int(0)
  ["client_info"]=>
  string(6) "5.5.29"
  ["client_version"]=>
  int(50529)
  ["connect_errno"]=>
  int(0)
  ["connect_error"]=>
  NULL
  ["errno"]=>
  int(0)
  ["error"]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["error_list"]=>
  array(0) {
  }
  ["field_count"]=>
  int(0)
  ["host_info"]=>
  string(25) "Localhost via UNIX socket"
  ["info"]=>
  NULL
  ["insert_id"]=>
  int(0)...

Comment: ["server_info"]=>
  string(6) "5.5.29"
  ["server_version"]=>
  int(50529)
  ["stat"]=>
  string(134) "Uptime: 17823  Threads: 1  Questions: 163  Slow queries: 0  Opens: 50  Flush tables: 1  Open tables: 43  Queries per second avg: 0.009"
  ["sqlstate"]=>
  string(5) "00000"
  ["protocol_version"]=>
  int(10)
  ["thread_id"]=>
  int(39)
  ["warning_count"]=>
  int(0)
}

Comment: @MissElizabeth Okay good, this means that you have setup the connection and you have a working object. We can now move on to debugging the query/execution of the query. What happens if you do a var_dump of `$result` after you run mysqli_query()? Have you checked that your query is valid (tried running it directly against the database? Such as in mysql workbench or phpmyadmin?)

Comment: When I run the $result I get bool(false). I don't know what you mean by if the query is valid; sorry I'm really new at this.

Comment: @MissElizabeth Not a problem! I'm here to help. What I mean by valid is that it doesn't have any syntax or logic errors, and that if you run it separately from PHP it works as expected. I've formatted your query in my answer and I think I found the problem, have a look at my updated answer.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to help me. I can't seem to find your updated answer. The answer above looks the same as your original answer.

Comment: Ok so, I fixed all of the problems with the queries, but the $result isn't returning anything, not even an error.

Comment: Hmm. What does $result specifically say if you var_dump it after running the query? Does it return null? If so then that means there is nothing in the database that is returned from the query.